# mysql - select with case priority result

Tags: mysql, sql

I've two tables

```
table1

| a_id  | a_name  |
+-------+---------+
|   1   |  foo    |
|   2   |  bar    |
|   3   |  joe    |
|   4   |  jhon   |

table2

| b_id  | a_id |  b_exec |
+-------+------+---------+
|   1   |   1  |    2    |
|   2   |   1  |    1    |
|   3   |   1  |    0    |
|   4   |   2  |    2    |
|   5   |   2  |    0    |
|   6   |   3  |    2    |
```

I would like to get a view with a b_exec_level.
The logic of b_exec_level should be this.
Giving priority to 1 then to 0 and then 2
If exist 1 in b_exec, exec_level must be 1
If exist 0 and not exist 1 in b_exec, exec_level must be 0
If 1 or 0 not exist, exec_level must be 2.

The result should be this

```
view

| a_id | a_nome | b_exec_level |
+------+--------+--------------+
|  1   |  foo   |      1       |
|  2   |  bar   |      0       |
|  3   |  joe   |      2       |
|  4   |  jhon  |      2       |
```

I've tried whit CASE in this way

```
select
t1.a_id,
t1.a_name,
( case when ( t2.b_exex = 0) then 0
       when ( t2.b_exex = 1) then 1 else 2 end) AS b_exec_level
from ( table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on( (t1.a_id = t2.a_id) ) )
group by t1.a_id;
```

but the result depends on the order in which they are data in t1.b_exec, if it has been inserted before the value 1 or 0.

You can do it in some way this thing?
Thanks

Comment: Just to further clarify, would you mind posting the table of results you get for the query you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track; one way is to use conditional aggregation based filtering. `sum(t2.b_exec = 1)` will be considered when there is atleast one row for `b_exec = 1`. Similarly, for other cases, as shown below:

```
select
t1.a_id,
t1.a_name,
( case when sum(t2.b_exec = 1) then 1 
       when sum(t2.b_exec = 0) then 0 
       else 2
  end ) AS b_exec_level
from ( table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on( (t1.a_id = t2.a_id) ) )
group by t1.a_id, t1.a_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
declare @tbl table(a_id int, b_exec int);
insert into @tbl values
(1, 2),
(1, 1),
(1, 0),
(2, 2),
(2, 0),
(3, 2);

select a_id,
       -- here we check existence of particular numbers and assign levels
       case when exist1 = 1 then 1 else
         case when exist0 = 1 then 0 else 2 end
       end b_exec_level
from (
    select a_id
           , max(case when b_exec = 0 then 1 else 0 end) exist0
           , max(case when b_exec = 1 then 1 else 0 end) exist1
           , max(case when b_exec = 2 then 1 else 0 end) exist2
    from @tbl
    group by a_id
) a
```